# Is MongoDb suited for my application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, non-relational-database, nosql

I'm building an application on node.js that has users and products in a many-to-many relationship (one user has many products and the same product might belong to multiple users). Each user has also location info.

Mostly I need to do a lot of writes on the user first visit (a few writes on the following visits) and then I need to match users that, for instance, have the most number of products in common and return that same products in common. I may also want to match users by location (or sort them by matching location)

I'm using postgres right now but I think I would be better of doing mongo in the long run. Problem is that I never worked on NOSQL DB (no fears ;) )

The question is, is the following "schema" suited for the described above?

```
[user]{
_id
name
age
[location]{
           streep
           town
           country
          }
}  

[products]{
_id
name
color
[users]{
        user_id_1
        user_id_2
        user_id_3
        }
}
```

I think, because of the requirements, I'm better of this way than with embeding. Am I right? Do you think I should store the products_id in the user document?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just curious, why do you think mongo is better? Are you having any problems in using your current DB with your requirements?

Comment: Well for one the performance which I hear to be a lot better (seen some promising graphics) and I'm having some problems with the postgres implementation I'm using for node.js which is kind of frustrating me. Do you think I should stick with postgres? thanks!!

Comment: Was just wondering why you were doing the switch. The mongo driver for node is pretty good and there are lots of frameworks so no worries on that. But if you're going to work with joined data it's not going to be as clean as on a relational DB. Depends on how much duplication of data you are willing to put up with. Normalization takes a bit of a hit on mongodb because the use cases are a bit different.

Comment: To get a good overview of the different aspects of the schema modeling you can take a look at the links in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226528/mongodb-table-design-and-query-performance/8226730#8226730

Comment: Thanks @hellectronic!! I'm looking into that

Comment: @JohnP Thanks for the info! I thought that I would be putting to much replication because I was just associating another user_id to product. I know my data is relational but I thought I could speed up things with Mongo... Anyway this is an over simplified schema and there are many fields that might or might not exists in user table/document. I might stick with postgres or even change to mysql (which I know best) if mongo is not so suited for this use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data seems quite relational to me.  I would not see a great advantage for MongoDB or NoSQL solutions.  They work well for document-based solutions that aren't relational.

I would get some data if you're having problems with scaling or performance.  Don't assume a solution until you know what the root cause is.  It could be node.js - who knows?  [Some people](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=node.js%20criticism) don't care much for it.

Comment: There are some very good points in there but, for me, node.js advantage is to work on a widely accepted language like javascript it's simplicity to use. The way I see it it's kind of server cost/eficiency vs your time cost and efficiency. That being said it's definitly nice to be informed and prepared when node (eventually) bites  but right now db performance is main issue. About 2000 average inserts on first visit and only after that can node do it's magic (this goes a bit against node principle but I think i have a solution) Thanks!!